# How to redirect all html files in a domain to a specific webpage?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 bluehost accounts. One belongs to a former employee and the other is our companies new one. We have several domains in the old account, like chinafabrix.com and we want all domains to redirect to our new website vitasino.com. The thing is that we dont just want chinafabrix.com to redirect but also chinafabrix.com/index.html chinafabrix.com/whatever.html chinafabrix.com/blahah.html  etc etc to redirect to vitasino.com (not vitasino.com/x.html  but only vitasino.com)

Is there any way of doing this without writing a separate redirect in all the html files in the domain?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.vitasino.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**or**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://vitasino.com/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the site root .htaccess of your old site you can place this single catch-all rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?chinafabrix\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)?$ http://vitasino.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```